# Using dplyr with filter, group_by & tail?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's an example df:

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:30, y = 101:130, g = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", "y", "g"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to get the 10 lowest values of y for each group within the filtered data.

But

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(x>3) %>% group_by(g) %>%  tail(y, n=10)
```

only returns the rows for the last group (C in this case):

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: g

    x   y g
18 21 121 C
19 22 122 C
20 23 123 C
21 24 124 C
22 25 125 C
23 26 126 C
24 27 127 C
25 28 128 C
26 29 129 C
27 30 130 C
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually mean the _lowest_ values of `y` or the last entries per group?

Comment: @beginneR you're totally right, I meant the lowest (not last) entries per group, which is probably the same in my original df but does matter of course. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Just note that `tail` only selects the last entries of a vector or data.frame (the last rows in that case), so unless you sort your data beforehand, `tail` doesn't necessarily select the lowest values (only by chance if they happen to be in that place).

Comment: One more question: what do you want in case of ties? just select exactly 10 rows or select all rows where the value of `y` is among the 10 lowest values?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `tail` inside `do`.

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(x>3) %>% group_by(g) %>%  do(tail(., n=10))
```

The use of `.` is key for this to work.  From the `do` help page: "You can use . to refer to the current group."

Edit:

As @beginneR pointed out, I was focusing on how to use `tail` in groups with `dplyr` and missed the part of the question where the OP asked for the 10 *lowest* values of `y`.  To do this correctly would take the addition of `arrange`.  With `tail`, this would mean arranging by descending order of `y`.

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(x>3) %>% group_by(g) %>%  arrange(desc(y)) %>% do(tail(., n=10))
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are two other options:

```
df %>% filter(x>3) %>% group_by(g) %>% top_n(3, desc(y))
```

Here we make use of `top_n` but use `desc(y)` since we want the *lowest* `y` values instead of the largest ("top") `y` values.

```
df %>% filter(x>3) %>% group_by(g) %>% arrange(y) %>% filter(1:n() <= 10)
```

which is equal to

```
df %>% filter(x>3) %>% group_by(g) %>% arrange(y) %>% slice(1:10)
```

After the grouping, we sort each group by increasing `y` and then select the first 10 rows per group (or less if there are not 10 rows in a group).

Since there was some confusion about lowest and last values to be selected: this answer selects the *lowest* values, not the last entries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `tail` isn't working, but you might try this:

```
df %>% 
 filter(x > 3) %>% 
 group_by(g) %>% 
 filter(.,rank(desc(y),ties.method = "min") <= 10)
```

Comment: Great, thanks, did not know about rank. Hope it's okay to wait a bit before accepting to see if someone has a solution with tail.

Comment: Use of 'tail' in question makes me think use of `rank` with `ties.method="min"` might not be right. For example: `rank(c(1,1,2,2,3),ties.method="min") < 3` returns four values...

Comment: @Spacedman You're right, I was mainly trying to mimic what Hadley did in `top_n`.

Comment: @beginneR That depends on what exactly the OP meant, which at the moment is ambiguous. All the answers thus far can be easily tweaked in either direction if needed.

Comment: @joran yes, that's correct and also the reason I deleted my comment again and asked the OP what he's trying to do. I was just a bit irritated by the description lowest values.

Comment: @beginneR No worries!

Comment: do you need the `.`? Can't you just use `filter(min_rank(desc(y)) <= 10)`?

Answer (score 2):

moar answers!  This is a good job for one of the "window functions" that calculates ranks.

```
df %>%
  filter(x > 3) %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  filter(y %>% min_rank <= 10)
```

Comment: This again doesn't select the lowest values as (in the meantime) specified by the OP. Check it out if you select 3 instead of 10.

Comment: @beginneR thanks for pointing that out!  my mistake was using `desc`.  Does it work now, or did I totally misunderstand the question? :P

Comment: Looks good now. The sample data are not well chosen (or the decision to select 10 rows) since in some groups there are less than 10 rows after the first filter, so it's not obvious that the function is different from what is desired (although the result may happen to be as desired)

Comment: why do you pipe in `filter`? Can't you just use `filter(min_rank(y) <= 10)` ?

Comment: @rrs because it's pretty.  With `magrittr` one could even say `y %>% min_rank %>% is_weakly_less_than(10)`
I suppose if I had to justify my behaviour, I'd say that it is good to see the filtering variable immediately on the left, rather than hunting through nested parentheses to find it.

Answer (score 2):

More compact syntax via `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)

# original tail question
dt[x > 3, tail(y, 10), by = g]

# 10 smallest values of y
# many options for this, here's one:
dt[x > 3, head(sort(y), 10), by = g]

# here's another, trying to take advantage of setkey speed
setkey(dt, g, y)
dt[x > 3, head(y, 10), by = g]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should tail work with a grouped data frame? It doesn't know about groups.

Add an order column, select by that column, drop that column. Here I use 3 instead of 10 for compactness (and %.% because old version of dplyr):

```
> df %.% filter(x>3) %.% group_by(g) %.% mutate(i=order(y)) %.% filter(i <= 3) %.% select(-matches("i"))
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: g

   x   y g
1  4 104 A
2  5 105 A
3  6 106 A
4 11 111 B
5 12 112 B
6 13 113 B
7 21 121 C
8 22 122 C
9 23 123 C
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I don't get your first argument, `mean`, `sum`, etc. don't "know" about groups either, isn't that the whole point of using dplyr or similar grouping functions? So how is `tail` different?

Comment: When using `mean` with `dplyr` you put it in a `summarise` and get a single value. You cant just pipe it into `mean`...