# Remove several rows based on one row

Tags: r, dplyr

In the data.frame below, I have 3 variables. id (A1 to A10); var A to E and value. I want to remove specific rows based on these conditions

For each variable `var` (A, B, C, D or E);

> If `id == A5` and
>
> if `value < 5`

then

remove all rows (10 rows) for this specific variable.

I will appreciate any suggestions how to do that.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", 
"A10", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"), class = "factor"), 
    var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), value = c(2, 4, 7, 
    8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 4, 2, 1, 22, 54, 21, 
    36, 52, 14, 75, 12, 15, 24, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 21, 22, 12, 
    12, 12, 0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 2, 3, 2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7)), .Names = c("id", 
"var", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L
))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512873/using-dplyr-with-filter-group-by-tail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr` using `group_by` and `filter`, we remove the group (`var`) which has `any` occurrence of `id` as "A5" and `value` less than 5.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(var) %>%
   filter(!any(id == 'A5' & value < 5))
```

Comment: @Noobie I kind of got it but would have been better if expected output was shared.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(!(id == 'A5' & value < 5), var, FUN = any)),]
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[any(!(id == 'A5' & value  < 5))], var]$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

well you can always do

```
df %>% filter((id != A5) | (value >= 5))
```

Comment: IMHO, this doesn't provide the answer for OP's question. So this shouldn't be here. :)